# Copy array variable to another array variable

Tags: java, arrays

I'd like to copy an array variable from one array to the array variable of another array.  How would I do that? Is it just `Array1[1] = Array2[1]` ?

Comment: Welcome, first you should give it a try...

Answer (score 3):

If you write

```
 array1[1] = array2[1];
```

that will copy the *value* of the second element of `array2` into the second element of `array1`. If that's all you wanted to do, that's fine.

It *won't* associate the two arrays together. If you then write:

```
 array2[1] = someNewValue();
```

then that change *won't* be visible in `array1`.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple...

`array1[1] = array2[1];`

**But mind that these 2 are two different Array Object on the heap, change in one won't reflected in other.**